# Allow Community User to Email Chatter Files

Tags: apex, community, email

I have a trigger on FeedItem that sends an email to all case participants with the content of the post, plus any attachments. This works well for small attachments, but once they get to be larger, Salesforce turns them into a content delivery and sends a link. This works when as a full user I post a file, but when my community user posts a large file, the email fails with `System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: NO_ATTACHMENT_PERMISSION, User cannot send Content attachment: []`.

The community profile doesn't have a permission called "Deliver Uploaded Files and Personal Content" which I think is what is needed to send the links. How can I get around this restriction?

Answer (score 0):

According to this help article, the users might need Community Plus or Partner Community licenses?

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214048&type=1

[image]

Comment: They are Community Plus users. They can upload just can't create a content delivery link (which happens automatically when you attach a large file)

Comment: Hrm, interesting. Might be a great question to also post on Success Community in the Chatter Product group and see if a PM can weigh in.